# How to override divi Menu.php to child theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming, divi

Divi does not come with default option for cart count on menu so I'm able to achieve this by editing wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/module/Menu.php but the problem it does not work if the file is put on child theme.

***Note***

- I tried put it in same path as parent theme
- tried to put it in "includes" directory
- menu is build using divi builder so editing header.php is no use.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Nope, I ended up using Divi MadMenu by  Ivan Chiurcci(Chi) ( https://www.divicio.us/ )

Answer (score 1):

Divi now comes with the option for cart count!

In the Divi Menu Module Go to Content >> Elements >> Show Cart Quantity

and toggle it on. Save, and the count should now be visible as soon as someone adds anything to their cart.